# Generate EDSCA recoverable signature for use with OpenZeppelin EDSCA contract (Embedded/C/C++ Hardware wallet)

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, ecdsa, hardware-wallets, secp256k1, embedded

I'd like to sign a message on an Arduino-compatible microcontroller, and create a **recoverable** signature which can be used with [EIP-191](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191) and Ethereum's *erecover* / OpenZeppelin's [ECDSA smart contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#ECDSA) to verify the signature's signer.

I've tried [Micro-ECC](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc)'s [*uECC_sign()*](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/blob/master/uECC.c#L1341) but it only supports regular signatures with a length of 64 (opened related question in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kmackay/micro-ecc/issues/201)).

- could this call be adapted? e.g. could the 65th bit be extracted along the process and inserted into the created signature, or are recoverable signatures following a different process when signing altogether?

I've also tried using the [secpk256k1 lib](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) too since it supports recoverable signatures ootb, but the result is still invalid when testing with [OZ's ECDSA contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#ECDSA).

In contrast, when signing the hash directly in my wallet (e.g. MEW), i get a valid signature that resolves to the signer's address.

```
// https://github.com/diybitcoinhardware/secp256k1-embedded > https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1
#include "secp256k1.h"
#include "secp256k1_recovery.h"

// private key: 0xbdb51a16eb6461ec16f84a7b6f19e20d0b9aa558fa0e9ae4bb493ff779f14255
// wallet address: 0x77baedd3f1aab1e8415bb6445cdaf418aa1924d5
static const uint8_t privateKey[] = {
    0xbd, 0xb5, 0x1a, 0x16, 0xeb, 0x64, 0x61, 0xec,
    0x16, 0xf8, 0x4a, 0x7b, 0x6f, 0x19, 0xe2, 0x0d,
    0x0b, 0x9a, 0xa5, 0x58, 0xfa, 0x0e, 0x9a, 0xe4,
    0xbb, 0x49, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0x79, 0xf1, 0x42, 0x55
};
// keccak256 of "1234": 0x387a8233c96e1fc0ad5e284353276177af2186e7afa85296f106336e376669f7
uint8_t hash[32] = {
  0x38, 0x7a, 0x82, 0x33, 0xc9, 0x6e, 0x1f, 0xc0,
  0xad, 0x5e, 0x28, 0x43, 0x53, 0x27, 0x61, 0x77,
  0xaf, 0x21, 0x86, 0xe7, 0xaf, 0xa8, 0x52, 0x96,
  0xf1, 0x06, 0x33, 0x6e, 0x37, 0x66, 0x69, 0xf7
};

// setup
secp256k1_context* ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN);
secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature sig;
uint8_t signature[65];
int recId;

// sign hash and serialize signature
secp256k1_ecdsa_sign_recoverable(ctx, &sig, hash, privateKey, NULL, NULL);
secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_serialize_compact(ctx, signature, &recId, &sig);
// fix recovery bit for Solidity
signature[64] = (recId == 0x00) ? 0x1b : 0x1c;

// expected signature: 65f333960946f37b57336199fd98826f4b334f70137f5f3a7ef2b2622007c6d77905672bd78dce53e37eb3ddef0c2219296db1795b466b5a89ffecda9d2106fc1c
// actual signature  : 2981840499f452d6dcef73808a4bee846a0d25559b6218f61024be3ae8f7e49908835dbd349c0971ef9ed2167f663ead4ab238fe65d3db10728cd7ddb417f69c1c
```

have been looking at [mbedTLS](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls) and [openSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) too, but running out of ideas...

did anyone solve this use case in any way before? does anyone have any experience with this?
any help or clues appreciated greatly!

Comment: your comment on the github issue about adding `1b` or `1c` to the end of `uECC_sign` output helped me a lot. When I add `1c` its output I can recover the address using python `web3`'s `recoverHash`. Have you seen this: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/i-cant-get-correct-recovered-address-with-ecdsa-recover/36054/2 One interesting thing is that if I sign the keccak256 hash `1234` using python `eth_account` or `uECC_sign`, they give different signatures, but both signatures resolve to the same address (again, with python `web3` `recoverHash`)  Maybe ur sig needs to be changed smhw before testing